# How to Retrieve Data from ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I want to retrieve data from Array adapter and store it on database
like if a details of a scaned bluetooth is stored in a arrayadapter and i want to get that data and store it on my database.

Comment: see `Adapter#getItem`

Comment: can u alobrate it properly ?

Comment: what to elaborate? it gets the item from the given position: `"""Get the data item associated with the specified position in the data set."""`

Comment: and how i willl store it to database?

Comment: read `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase` docs

Comment: Please provide a basic working code example if possible. @pskink appears to have provided a couple of valuable resources.  Let us know how this worked out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add to your Adapter Class it will return all adapter items in a List, you can then do whatever you want with it

EDIT :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    MyAdapter<String> btArrayAdapter;   // don't forget to change type here

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        btArrayAdapter = new MyAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        listDevicesFound.setAdapter(btArrayAdapter);
        ...
    }


    public class MyAdapter<String> extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource) {
            super(context, resource);
        }

        //Adapter implementation
        //so this is the function that retrieve data from the adapter
        public List<String> getAllItems() { 
            ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>()
            for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                result.add(getItem(i));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

you can then retrieve data by calling `btArrayAdapter.getAllItems();`

For button on your xml:

```
 <Button
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:id="@+id/button"
     android:onClick="btnClick"
     android:text="save "/>
```

for Database you can add :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        //constant used for database
        private static final String DEVICE = "Device";
        private static final String BLUETOOTH_DEVICES = "BluetoothDevice";
        private static final String DATE = "date";

        SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //how to create or open databse
        myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",MODE_PRIVATE,null);

            // here we create a table like following
            // BluetoothDevice :
            // | Device : VARCHAR |
            // | date   : INTEGER |

        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + BLUETOOTH_DEVICES + "(" + DEVICE + " VARCHAR," + DATE + " INTEGER);");

    }

    private Map<String, Date> getItemFromDatabase() {
        Map<String,Date> result = new HashMap<>();
        //Query to retrieve data from database
        Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from " + BLUETOOTH_DEVICES, null);
        //how to iterate hover database cursor
        while (c.moveToNext()){
            result.put(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DEVICE)),new Date(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DATE))));
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }

    public void store(List<String> data){
        for (String value : data) {
            //Query to insert item in databse
            myDatabase.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+BLUETOOTH_DEVICES+" VALUES(?,?);",new String[]{value, String.valueOf(new Date().getTime())});
        }
    }

    //button click listenner defined in xml
    public void btnClick(View view) {
        // here we store all adapter item in database
        store(btArrayAdapter.getAllItems());
    }
}
```

You can add it to previous code.
It's just a base i Higly sugest you to reformat you code create diffrent java class, use sql data helper class and stuff

Comment: i need button when user click that button the whole data like spinner data and adapter data will be store to data base along with the date and time...any help please

Comment: i added button creation and listener to button click and VERY SIMPLE database creation it's jsut a base but it should work. hope it helps

Comment: thanks alot lary u help me alot....if any problem occurs i will let u know anything for stay in contact

Comment: hey i entered your code but when i clicked that button in my mobile..the application crashed unfortunetly Stop Help please

Comment: can you post logcat error message please? Maybe you forgot to put click methode on your activity class:  `public void btnClick(View view) { ... }`

Comment: oh it's becaus you have a quote in your bluetooth device name try changing :  `myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO "+BLUETOOTH_DEVICES+" VALUES('"+value+"','"+new Date().getTime()+"');");` by  `myDatabase.rawQuery("INSERT INTO "+BLUETOOTH_DEVICES+" VALUES(?,?);",new String[]{value, String.valueOf(new Date().getTime())});`  (i will also edit my answer)

Comment: Will it also save the Bluetooth adress?

Comment: hey i don't know what you are trying to achive but you should try to understand by yourself what is going on in the code, i'll edit my answer to remove your code and add comment to make it more clear but i think you should learn basics of [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/index.html) , [user interface](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html) and input commande, [database](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db) if you want to be able to code what you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help ...I understand your code one last question how can i acces my database hope you will me its my collage project

Comment: i will help you don't worry. i put exemple to access your database in code already. From any activity you can get you database by doing :     `myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("DATABASE",MODE_PRIVATE,null);` then you can make request onto database with `myDatabase.rawQuery(...);`

Comment: i created one more buton and one more list view when the user click that button the data save in a database will display in that listview along with date and time

Comment: i need help..i am totally new too android

Comment: Please help me once

Answer (score 0):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.test.test, PID: 17458
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3989)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4741)
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19384)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107)
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
   at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3984)
   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4741) 
   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19384) 
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5679) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1291) 
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1107) 
   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "s": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO BluetoothDevice VALUES('Faiz's iPhone
28:ED:6A:E0:E4:C8','1470825437206');
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1113)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:690)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:59)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
   at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1793)
```

Comment: if you just copy past it will not work, you have to undestand and adapt to your code... i'm sorry i can't help you more that that ...

Answer (score 0):

Ok like you requested i created an acticity with 2 list, on the first one we have a list of item. Under there is a button labeled "save" when you click on it, it will get all adapter item and store them into the database. Under, there is a button refresh, that will retrieve data drom database and display them on second list.

so for the xml we have: activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/list" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:onClick="btnSaveClick"
        android:text="Save" />

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:id="@+id/dbList" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:onClick="btnRefreshClick"
        android:text="refresh" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then have 3 java classes, one to define Bluetooth devices object one for the adapter and one for the activity.
first BluetoothDevice.java :

```
public class BluetoothDevice {
   public String name;
   public String address;
   public Date date;
   public String scan;

    public BluetoothDevice(String name, String address, Date date,String scan) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.date = date;
        this.scan =scan;
    }

    private SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMMM yyyy");

    public String getDateFormatted() {
        if (date == null){
            return " no date ";
        }
        return format.format(date);
    }
}
```

Second MyAdapter.java:

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<BluetoothDevice> {


    public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, List<BluetoothDevice> devices) {
        super(context, resource, devices);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // here we can define custom design of list item
        TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
        BluetoothDevice item = getItem(position);
        textView.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        textView.setText(item.name+" : "+item.address +"  date :"+item.getDateFormatted()+" "+item.scan);
        return textView;
    }


    //method to get all adapter objects
    public List<BluetoothDevice> getAllItem() {

        List<BluetoothDevice> result = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
            Log.e("fef", "getAllItem: " );
            result.add(getItem(i));
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

and finaly MyActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {


    SQLiteDatabase myDatabase;

    private MyAdapter adapter;

    private ListView listOfDatabaseObject;

    private ListView list;

    private String databaseName = "DATABASENAME2";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        listOfDatabaseObject = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.dbList);


        List<BluetoothDevice> devices = new ArrayList<>();

        //for the exemple i crate a new device to add to the list
        devices.add(new BluetoothDevice("device 1", "14:5E:FE:AA", null,"scan record : 78984f9s8d4f98 s4df98s4f 984sf 984sd9f8 4cucoucou 7f578sfd57f8"));


        adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, devices);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);

        myDatabase = openOrCreateDatabase(databaseName, MODE_PRIVATE, null);
        // here we create a table like following
        // BluetoothDevice :
        // | Device : VARCHAR |
        // | Address : VARCHAR |
        // | date   : VARCHAR |
        // | Scan   : VARCHAR |
        myDatabase.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS BluetoothDevice ( Device VARCHAR , Address VARCHAR , Date VARCHAR ,Scan VARCHAR);");


    }

    private List<BluetoothDevice> getItemFromDatabase() {
        List<BluetoothDevice> result = new ArrayList<>();
        // query database elements
        Cursor c = myDatabase.rawQuery("Select * from BluetoothDevice ;", null);

        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            Date v = new Date();
            v.setTime(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Date")) * 1000);
            Date date = new Date();
            date.setTime(Long.valueOf(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Date"))));
            result.add(
                    new BluetoothDevice(
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Device")),
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Address")),
                            date,
                            c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("Scan"))
                    )
            );
        }
        c.close();
        return result;
    }


    public void store(List<BluetoothDevice> data) {
        for (BluetoothDevice value : data) {
            String s = String.valueOf(new Date().getTime());
            //insert in database
            myDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO  BluetoothDevice VALUES(?,?,?,?);", new String[]{value.name, value.address, s,value.scan});

        }
    }

    // save button click listener
    public void btnSaveClick(View view) {
        store(adapter.getAllItem());
    }

    // refresh button click listener
    public void btnRefreshClick(View view) {
        List<BluetoothDevice> itemFromDatabase = getItemFromDatabase();
        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 0, itemFromDatabase);
        listOfDatabaseObject.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}
```

in this code you will find everything you need to **get all item from an adapter**, create a button and it's action, create a simple sqlite database, with custom field, **insert item** inside the database, **retrieve item** from the database, and finaly display them inside a a listview.

Comment: Myadapter<String> btArrayAdapter; should i change this too Array adapter this throwing an error

Comment: when i click save throwing the error i posted the logcat error

Comment: STOOOOP this code is stand alone code it have nothing to do with your code, don't try to include part of this code inside your. it's only a demo on how to implement things like button and click listenner, you have to adapt it for your code.

Comment: Okay i got it u helped me alot bro...one last help please please  devices.add(new BluetoothDevice("device 1", "14:5E:FE:AA", null)); how to add my scaned bluetooth details

Comment: change BluetoothDevice class, add a field to contain your scanned detail. add parameeter to constructor

Comment: Please edit the answer and remove that scan coloum please